# Identify the interval for empty box in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-cursor

I try to figure out the best approach to report the interval from a dataset when a box got empty. I have a stored procedure which give me the latest inventory (quantity) and after this inventory I got the table named export in which I can see movements on the box later on, at a point the box will be emptied and I want to know the start date and the end date till the box is empty.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[export]
(
    [idbox] [int] NULL,
    [actualquantity] [int] NULL,
    [actiondate] [datetime2](7) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, 0, CAST(N'2022-06-01T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, 0, CAST(N'2022-07-01T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, -1, CAST(N'2022-07-19T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, -6, CAST(N'2022-07-17T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, -14, CAST(N'2022-07-24T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, 0, CAST(N'2022-08-01T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, -5, CAST(N'2022-08-02T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, -9, CAST(N'2022-08-15T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, 34, CAST(N'2022-08-24T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, -34, CAST(N'2022-08-24T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, 34, CAST(N'2022-08-24T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, 0, CAST(N'2022-09-01T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO

INSERT [dbo].[export] ([idbox], [actualquantity], [actiondate]) 
VALUES (52473, 0, CAST(N'2022-10-01T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2))
GO
```

In this dataset the inventory is 35 pieces and in the attached data the box will be empty between

> 2022-08-15 00:00:00.0000000

and

> 2022-08-24 00:00:00.0000000

[image: Screenshot from a data set example]

The results about boxes I am carrying out using CURSOR on the existing boxes (existing boxes are returned from a stored procedure with the initial quantity from the latest inventory).

What approach should I use to loop on the results, should I use another CURSOR with some local variable in which I keep an eye on the box quantity while I am looping on the results?

Comment: The box will be empty on exactly `2022-08-15`.  Why would you want `2022-08-24`?

Comment: Why are you columns all `NULL`able? Why isn't there a PK? If you aren't storing the time-of-day then use `date` instead of `datetime2`.

Comment: _"should I use another CURSOR?"_ - It's not the 1990s anymore: you should never need to use a `CURSOR` in an RDBMS, especially not for reporting-purposes.

Comment: @DanGuzman it will be emptied at `2022-08-15` and will stay empty till `2022-08-24` it means it will stay empty ~9 days i need to know the start date when will be empty and when will be occupied again.

Comment: @Dai i imported in a temporary table so i can script it out the date the result set normally is returned by another query as i wrote in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial approach to this would be to have a 'current quantity' column in your table; but if you don't have that, you can approach it via calculations.

The key tools here are

- The [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function as an *analytic* function - by using the OVER clause
- The [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function which allows you to get a value from the next row of data

Note that in my dataset, I have made two tweaks on what you have above

- Added a PRIMARY KEY, auto-incrementing field called `Auto_ID`
- Added an initial row (on 1/1/2022) with `actualquantity` = 35 for this box (I'm assuming that the box, at some point, had to have 35 items put into it to start)

You can follow the logic at [this db_fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/_93gG1Mx)

**Using SUM to get a running total**

If you add an OVER clause with an ORDER BY to a SUM function, you make it have a running total - instead of just reporting the total for all rows.

The key purpose for calculating this running total is to identify when the box is empty - when the running total = 0.

The SQL for this is pretty simple - the PARTITION component says to do the totals within each box only (similar to a GROUP BY) and the ORDER BY is critical to how the running total is carried out.

```
SELECT  *,
        SUM(actualquantity) OVER (PARTITION BY idbox ORDER BY actiondate, Auto_ID) AS currentquantity
FROM    dbo.export;
```

**Using LEAD to get the next date**

This part allows you to get the next `actiondate` onto the current line. The purpose of this is that you can then do a DATEDIFF on these two dates to get the time between this `actiondate` and the next.

Note the OVER clause is the same as the SUM above.

```
SELECT  *,
        SUM(actualquantity) OVER (PARTITION BY idbox ORDER BY actiondate, Auto_ID) AS currentquantity,
        LEAD(actiondate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY idbox ORDER BY actiondate, Auto_ID) AS next_actiondate
FROM    dbo.export;
```

Using the above, the current results would be

```
Auto_ID     idbox       actualquantity actiondate                  currentquantity next_actiondate
----------- ----------- -------------- --------------------------- --------------- ---------------------------
1           52473       35             2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 35              2022-06-01 00:00:00.0000000
2           52473       0              2022-06-01 00:00:00.0000000 35              2022-07-01 00:00:00.0000000
3           52473       0              2022-07-01 00:00:00.0000000 35              2022-07-17 00:00:00.0000000
5           52473       -6             2022-07-17 00:00:00.0000000 29              2022-07-19 00:00:00.0000000
4           52473       -1             2022-07-19 00:00:00.0000000 28              2022-07-24 00:00:00.0000000
6           52473       -14            2022-07-24 00:00:00.0000000 14              2022-08-01 00:00:00.0000000
7           52473       0              2022-08-01 00:00:00.0000000 14              2022-08-02 00:00:00.0000000
8           52473       -5             2022-08-02 00:00:00.0000000 9               2022-08-15 00:00:00.0000000
9           52473       -9             2022-08-15 00:00:00.0000000 0               2022-08-24 00:00:00.0000000
10          52473       34             2022-08-24 00:00:00.0000000 34              2022-08-24 00:00:00.0000000
11          52473       -34            2022-08-24 00:00:00.0000000 0               2022-08-24 00:00:00.0000000
12          52473       34             2022-08-24 00:00:00.0000000 34              2022-09-01 00:00:00.0000000
13          52473       0              2022-09-01 00:00:00.0000000 34              2022-10-01 00:00:00.0000000
14          52473       0              2022-10-01 00:00:00.0000000 34              NULL
```

**Calculating number of days empty**

Using the above, we can calculate the number of days empty simply - when the `currentquantity` is 0, determine the number of days between this and the next `actiondate` (or today if it's still empty).

I've used a CTE which has the above SQL to get the relevant data, then reported the specific results.

```
WITH RunningTotals AS
    (SELECT *,
        SUM(actualquantity) OVER (PARTITION BY idbox ORDER BY actiondate, Auto_ID) AS currentquantity,
        LEAD(actiondate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY idbox ORDER BY actiondate, Auto_ID) AS next_actiondate
    FROM    dbo.export
    )
SELECT  idbox, actualquantity, actiondate,
        CASE WHEN currentquantity = 0
                THEN DATEDIFF(day, actiondate, ISNULL(next_actiondate, getdate()))
            ELSE NULL END AS emptydelay
FROM    RunningTotals
ORDER BY Auto_id;
```

Here are the results from the above - with the column 'emptydelay' representing the number of days the box was empty.

```
idbox       actualquantity actiondate                  emptydelay
----------- -------------- --------------------------- -----------
52473       35             2022-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       0              2022-06-01 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       0              2022-07-01 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       -1             2022-07-19 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       -6             2022-07-17 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       -14            2022-07-24 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       0              2022-08-01 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       -5             2022-08-02 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       -9             2022-08-15 00:00:00.0000000 9
52473       34             2022-08-24 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       -34            2022-08-24 00:00:00.0000000 0
52473       34             2022-08-24 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       0              2022-09-01 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
52473       0              2022-10-01 00:00:00.0000000 NULL
```